# C# Reading the Window name

Tags: c#, windows, winapi

So I'm working on an application that pastes things into RTF boxes or any text box really utilizing the clipboard.

I need to be able to tell what window users have selected so that my application can determine if it should paste the data there or not.

Is there a way to read the name of the currently selected window, so that I can determine if they should be able to past in it?

Thanks

Comment: Once the data is on the clipboard you have no control over where the user will paste it, even if you are able to determine the window they selected.  Perhaps you are talking about Drag/Drop.

Comment: You want to identify *external* EDIT/RICHEDIT windows? GetClassName/RealGetWindowClass

Comment: Child controls don't have names.  They have a class name, the value is unpredictable.  Some GUIs don't use windows at all, WPF and browser edit boxes are just pixels.  Use a UI Automation library to have a shot at this, like .NET's System.Windows.Automation namespace or Project White.

Comment: well this app globally watches for f6 to be pressed... i figured i could grab the active window after the wake up call and then prevent some data from going into the wrong window here at the hospital... they arent as tech savy as they thing they are....

Comment: Thanks for the link... i really wasnt sure how to phrase the question and couldnt find anything on it.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to get the name of a form you can do this

```
this.Name // Returns the current forms name

//or if you want the title of the form if you initialise multiple forms

this.Title // Gets the text at the top of the form
```

Comment: Im sorry, the op wanted to get the current active window.
This will do that, this.Name returns the current active win form window

Comment: I know how to get the window Im working with but this app pasts into an existing window... Not from one that I created.  It pasts into any application that takes text

Comment: Cheers for the confirmation HellKnight